# Excel: How to identify duplicate values in separate Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, validation, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I have two separate Excel files that have a column "Q".

If both files have the same value anywhere in column "Q", I need to identify the row that has this value in file #1.

OBJECTIVE:

- I need to ensure that file #1'S column "Q" only consists of values that are not present in file #2's column "Q".
- If file #1 contains a row that has a column "Q" value in column "Q" of file #2, I want to highlight or remove this row in file #1.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

1. I added both files in the same workbook to solve reference issues. So now file #1 = "Sheet1" and file #2 = "Sheet2".

I applied the following formula to every cell within file #1's column "Q" --> =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$3413, Q1)>0

3413 is the amount of rows in file #2.

This approach highlights every single row.

My main thought is that I'm simply not referencing the correct files, but the fact that the conditional formatting executes rather than providing an error message leads me to believe that this may not be the case.

UPDATE:
I have now tried copying file #2's column Q ( 1220 rows ) into file #1's column R ( 3413 rows ).

- I then applied the following formula to every cell in file #1's column Q: =ISNUMBER(MATCH(Q2,$R$2:$R$3413,0))
- I am still experiencing the same behavior, every row is being highlighted.

Comment: You can use `MATCH()` to flag duplicate values.   FYI if you include something specific that you tried and explain what issues you had with that approach, people are more likely to help.

Comment: If you put that formula `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$3413, Q1)` in a column in file1, does it count duplicates?  FYI MATCH is probably faster if you only need to know if there's at least one match `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(Q1,Sheet2!$Q$2:$Q$3413,0))`

Answer (score 1):

This will work (both lists on same sheet for clarity)

[image]

Comment: Sir, `ISNUMBER()` wrapping is also not required as in `Conditional Formatting` the `#N/A` values will not be highlighted, only those have a number will get highlighted

Comment: Good point but I like being explicit with respect to generating a true/false rather than truthy/falsy

Comment: Gotcha thanks for the tip=)

Comment: I tested this approach with a small data set and it worked correctly! However, I attempted this approach in my actual solution - see UPDATE below and in initial question above.

Comment: UPDATE: I have now tried copying file #2's column Q ( 1220 rows ) into file #1's column R ( 3413 rows ).

I then applied the following formula to every cell in file #1's column Q: =ISNUMBER(MATCH(Q2,$R$2:$R$3413,0))

I am still experiencing the same behavior, every row is being highlighted.

Comment: There's only a single process to apply the CF: (1) Select *the whole range to be formatted* (2) Add a CF rule as shown, with "C3" from the screenshot being replaced by the address (in non-absolute format) of the first cell in the selected range, and the lookup list address (in absolute format) pointing to $R$2:$R$3413.   You don't need to apply the CF rule cell-by-cell.

Comment: What I'm hearing is each row is being highlighted because the value of Q2 is present in column R ( the same rule is being applied to every cell within the selected range - checking for the value of Q2 being in column R ). What I'm not able to figure out is how to loop through each cell and search for that value in column R ( is Q3 in column R, is Q4 in column R, etc. ). Forgive me for redundancy as I'm learning Excel on the fly. I see that it is very dynamic!

Comment: Excel adjusts the CF formula dynamically for each cell - you don’t need to do that yourself